# DELETE SQL script does not run. Error points to the 'join' and I'm not sure why

Tags: mysql-error-1064

DELETE SQL script does not run. Error points to the 'join' and I'm not sure why.
DELETE
FROM [OUTPATIENT].[dbo].[AR Report 20210119] a
join adhoc.[dbo].[bj_zerochg] b
on a.[COID-CASE-DOS]=b.[COID-CASE-DOS]

Comment: Are you trying to delete from both tables? What is the full message? Is the error different if you specify the table aliases after the delete? e.g. `DELETE a, b FROM...`

Comment: My goal is to only delete from table 'a'. SO yes, this version works: DELETE a
FROM [OUTPATIENT].[dbo].[AR Report 20210119] a
INNER JOIN adhoc.[dbo].[bj_zerochg] b
  ON a.[COID-CASE-DOS]=b.[COID-CASE-DOS]

Comment: put Error In Your Question

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what table you are deleting from. Here is a version:

```
DELETE a
FROM [OUTPATIENT].[dbo].[AR Report 20210119] a
INNER JOIN adhoc.[dbo].[bj_zerochg] b
  ON a.[COID-CASE-DOS]=b.[COID-CASE-DOS]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Thank you!

Comment: @Beki It's only deleted from the alias "a" table.

Comment: Yes, got it. That was my goal. Thank you.